# Dictionary to HTML table which can be searched from the results

Tags: python, html, json

I have a university assignment which is to send and receive data via json on a python script via a server and to then display this in a browser with a add and search field. I am adding a students name, surname and age to the dictionary. Please accept my apologises as I'm not the best when it comes to coding.

Currently I can send the information inputted to the received script and it shows as a python dictionary on the python script. I know need to look at getting this to display in a browser e.g chrome with a fuction that can add new students but also search the data dictionary.

Im really struggling how to get the data dictionary to display in a browser. currently it shows on the received script and I can out put with a .txt file with the information.

I'm probably describing this in a rubbish way but any help would be great.

Tired to export as html instead of txt , but I can't find a way of formatting the data and adding a search function. Ive added the data dictionary part below and where it out puts the data to the receive file and a .txt file.

```
student[fname +" " + sname] = {#assign data to dictionary
    'Student First name':fname,
    'Student Last name':sname,
    'Student Age':age,
    'pass':passed
    }

go = input("\n press x to exit  OR any key to continue")

if go in ["x","X"]:
    print     ("\n data being sent")
    jsonFile = json.dumps(student)#create json file from your dictionary
    s.send(jsonFile.encode('utf-8'))
    thing = False
    print     ("\n data sent")
    time.sleep(5)

    with open('student.txt', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(student, json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

make a html template to take arguments and display the data.  like this one.
Add the fields to search and manage the search yourself.

```
<html>
    <title>User Data</title>
    <body>
        <head>Your head</head>
        <p>
            Available Student Data in the Database
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> fname</td>
                    <td> sname</td>
                    <td> age</td>
                    <td> passed</td>
                </tr>
                {% for user in users %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{user.fname}}</td>
                    <td> {{user.sname}}</td>
                    <td> {{user.age}}</td>
                    <td> {{user.passed}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

then render this html using `render_template` function of `flask` library
like this

```
render_template('user_data.html',users=your_user_data)
```

make sure that your_user_data is list of students with the specified attributes as written in html template.

Comment: Hi , i will take a look at this now and see what i can do , thanks for the help . i will get back to you asap

Answer (score 0):

As you say :

> send and receive data via json on a python script via a server

So basically, you miss the server part. For your case, you'll need a **Python web server** that you can then connect to your Python script.

Have a look on different Python web server by yourself ;)
For a little projet like that, i recommend you `Flask`, but that's my opinion.
For sure, don't use Django for that.

Comment: Hi , i have the python server that makes the two talk together im just looking to make the receive  script output to html instead of on the script